# WebdriverIO Chromedriver service fails after installation

Tags: webdriver-io

I am a beginner for webdriverIO. I have started with TestRunner with the help of web driver IO docs.
I installed node and get expected a response for this command

```
./node_modules/.bin/wdio --help
```

I defined configuration using

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config
```

But when I am running

```
./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js
```

it is giving me following error

```
Error: Couldn't initialise launcher from service "chromedriver".
Error: Cannot find module 'chromedriver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/userName/node_modules/wdio-chromedriver-service/build/launcher.js:9:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Launcher.getLauncher (/Users/userName/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/launcher.js:815:35)
    at Launcher._callee$ (/Users/userName/node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/launcher.js:234:49)
    at tryCatch (/Users/userName/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/userName/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/userName/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
    at step (/Users/userName/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at /Users/userName/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:35:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (/Users/userName/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:36:28)
    at Launcher.<anonymous> (/Users/userName/node_modules/webdriverio/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:14:12)
```

Answer (score 9):

I've had this issue before. It comes down to `wdio-chromedriver-service` not installing `chromedriver` as a dependency.

To fix this issue, simply run:
`npm i chromedriver --save-dev`

Comment: I was struggling with this. Thanks Kevin. You have always been a saver when it comes to Automated Visual testing.